# Animation In Menu Like Angry Birds or Tiny Wings

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4

I was wondering how to add a scrolling menu to my app like tiny wings or angry birds. In tiny wings, the background moves from right to left and I was wondering how they accomplished that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with either app (yes, a gaming Ludite), but if you make a view wider than the screen you can move it's location/center/frame/transform/etc. to make it move, you can animate that action too.

if you make the first 320 points (we measure in points, not pixels) of the width of the view equal to the last 320 points, you can jump the view's location when it reaches the end and keep going for ever.

---

Edit (example code):

```
- (void)animateBannerLocation {
  UIView *view = _bannerView; // _bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1000 ish,40);
  CGRect startRect = view.frame;
  CGRect destinationRect = view.frame;
  // assuming superview is width of screen
  destinationRect.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(view.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(view.superview.frame);
  [UIView animateWithDuration:6.0 // time in seconds
                   animations:^(void) {
                     view.frame = destinationRect;
                   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     /** if you want it to scroll forever:
                     view.frame = startRect;
                     [self animateBannerLocation];
                      **/
                   }];
}
```

untested

---

Edit #2
also untested

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIImageView *_bannerView; /// - an ivar
  // not the best way to load an image you only use in one place:
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SomeBigBannerImage1000x40ish.png"];
  _bannerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
  [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];
}
```

---

Edit #3

Reviewed your code.  You should pay attention to the compiler warnings.

```
- (void)animateBannerLocation {
  UIView *view = _bannerView; // _bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,1000 ish,40);
  CGRect startRect = view.frame;
  CGRect destinationRect = view.frame;
  // assuming superview is width of screen
  destinationRect.origin.x = - (CGRectGetWidth(view.frame) - CGRectGetWidth(view.superview.frame));
  [UIView animateWithDuration:6.0 
                        delay:0.0 
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                   animations:^(void) {
                     view.frame = destinationRect;
                   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     view.frame = startRect;
                     if (stopAnimation == NO)
                       [self animateBannerLocation];
                   }];

}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  [self animateBannerLocation];
}
```

Comment: How would you recommend I move the view? Could you provide a sample code or site I could look at? Also, How would I set the view to reset back to the first 320 pixels after it reaches the end?

Comment: I think this code works but I am getting one error I don't know how to fix. what should I put in place of _bannerView; I am using a normal view Controller that has a view in the xib file automatically. So what should I put in place of _bannerView; ? Thanks for all the help and sorry if I sound a bit dumb.

Comment: Ok I got the the second way to work. But the image is not scrolling. Am I supposed to use both of the methods together?

Comment: yeah, you should invoke `animateBannerLocation` once - `viewDidAppear:` is a good place for that

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong! The project is building correctly, yet my banner does not scroll! If you don't mind, it would be really great if you could take a look at my project. http://www.mediafire.com/?4ev1va67mh7vc0d I would really appreciate it! Thanks.